# No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined after OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jsf-2

Well, Because LazyInitializationException i needed to add the "OpenSessionViewInFilter" in my web.xml, with the following code:

```
<!--  openSessionInViewfilter -->
 <filter>  
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>  
    </filter>  

    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

The problem is after i added this code, i got the following error when i try start TOMCAT 7:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I don't know why this error occurrs, because i'm using Entitymanager (JPA) and not SessionFactory, see my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Seta anotaçoes para serem usadas pelo Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define o pacote onde o Spring vai procurar por beans anotados -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="br.com.sender" />

    <!-- define que as transaçoes irao ser anotadas -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" /> 

    <!-- Configuracao do Banco de Dados -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sender" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="pgadmin" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="senderPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add both snippets below

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

and

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then you need to add **spring-orm-{our version here}.jar** to your classpath. Like this if you're using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.ver}</version>
</dependency>
```

--EDIT--

Sorry, I'm using JPA, your code suggests you are using hibernate3 so your filter-class should be **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter**

Comment: thanks this works. This OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter is specific to JPA and the other to HIBERNATE ?

Comment: @Mr.Lanhellas Please check my EDIT above. :)

Comment: I'm using JPA too, with hibernate but working with EntityManager.

Comment: @Mr.Lanhellas I'm using JPA with Hibernate implementation, my first snippet should work for you then. :)

Comment: i tried but i have another problem: After login in my application i got a LazyInitializationException (session was closed) when i try call a lazy property.

Comment: @Mr.Lanhellas I think, in this case, the problem is because your relationship is annotated as Lazy. You need to either change to eager or load it using one of those Hibernate Util methods. Just keep in mind that changing to eager, your entity will always load the relationship with might create performance problems in the future.

Comment: I can't understand what is the proxy objective if i need to load my lazy entities with "join fetch" in a query. I expected that i call "user.getAddress()" and proxy make a SELECT searching ADDRESS for me, but if session was closed i can't do it and proxy isn't util for me.

Comment: @Desorder you are awesome.. I spent more than two days to resolve lazy initialization error as I wanted to achieve only by Fetch lazy not Fetch eager.You answer helped me a lot.